# How does the Shell executor run scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab-ci-runner

We've recently moved to Gitlab and have started using pipelines. We've set up a build server (an Ubuntu 16.04 instance) and installed a runner that uses a Shell executor but I'm unsure of how it actually executes the scripts defined in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. Consider the following snippet of code:

```
script:
    - sh authenticate.sh $DEPLOY_KEY
    - cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh && cd .. 
    - sh deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING
    - sh deauthenticate.sh
```

I was under the impression that it will just pipe these commands to Bash, and hence I was expecting the default Bash behaviour. What happens, however, is that the `deploy.sh` fails because of an `ssh` error ; Bash then continues to execute `deploy_service.sh` (which is expected behaviour) however this fails with a `can't open deploy_service.sh` error and the job terminates without Bash executing the last statement.

From what I understand, Bash will only abort on error if you do a `set -e` first and hence I was expecting all the statements to be executed. I've tried adding the `set -e` as the first statement but this makes no difference whatsoever - it doesn't terminate on the first `ssh` error.

I've added the exact output from Gitlab below:

Without `set -e`

```
$ cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh && cd ..
deploy.sh: 72: deploy.sh: Bad substitution
Building JS bundles locally...

> better-npm-run build

running better-npm-run in x
Executing script: build

to be executed: node ./bin/build 
-> building js bundle...
-> minifying js bundle...
Uploading JS bundles to server temp folder...
COMMENCING RESTART. 5,4,3,2,1...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname $: Name or service not known
$ sh deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING
sh: 0: Can't open deploy_service.sh
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

With `set -e`

```
$ set -e
$ cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh && cd ..
deploy.sh: 72: deploy.sh: Bad substitution
Building JS bundles locally...

> better-npm-run build

running better-npm-run in x
Executing script: build

to be executed: node ./bin/build 
-> building js bundle...
-> minifying js bundle...
Uploading JS bundles to server temp folder...
COMMENCING RESTART. 5,4,3,2,1...
ssh: Could not resolve hostname $: Name or service not known
$ sh deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING
sh: 0: Can't open deploy_service.sh
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

Why is it, without `set -e`, terminating on error (also, why is it terminating on the second error only and not the `ssh` error)? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "sh deploy.sh" You're invoking `sh` here, not `bash`. They may not be the same thing on your system. If you want bash, invoke bash.

Comment: @Kenster  `bash` is used to invoke `sh` on that script and the error is returned to `bash` with the appropriate exit code (127 for first error and 255 for second error). The problem is that ` bash` is/isn't detecting the error as it's expected to.

Comment: From the docs:                                                                                            # This command is used if the build should be executed in context of another user (the shell executor)
`cat generated-bash-script | su --shell /bin/bash --login user`

Comment: Just because `sh` is linked to `bash` doesn't mean that `bash` behaves the same in both cases.  See [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html): "If Bash is invoked with the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh as closely as possible, while conforming to the POSIX standard as well." for example

Answer (score 0):

Gitlab script block is  actuality an array of shell scripts.
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#script
Failure in each element of array will fail a whole array.
To workaround put your script block in some script.sh file

like

```
script:
    - ./script.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your `sh deploy.sh` is generating a non-zero exit code.

You are using `set -e` to tell the current process to exit if a command exits with a non-zero return code, but you are creating a sub-process to run the shell script.

Here's a simple example script that I've called `deploy.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First."
echox "Error"
echo "Second"
```

If I run the script, you can see how the error is not handled:

```
$ sh deploy.sh 
First.
deploy.sh: line 5: echox: command not found
Second
```

If I run `set -e` first, you will see it has no effect.

```
$ set -e
$ sh deploy.sh 
First.
deploy.sh: line 5: echox: command not found
Second
```

Now, I add `-e` to the `/bin/bash` shebang:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
echo "First."
echox "Error"
echo "Second"
```

When I run the script with `sh` the `-e` **still** takes no effect.

```
$ sh ./deploy.sh 
First.
./deploy.sh: line 3: echox: command not found
Second
```

When this script is run directly using bash, the `-e` takes effect.

```
$ ./deploy.sh 
First.
./deploy.sh: line 3: echox: command not found
```

To fix your issue I believe you need to:

- Add `-e` to the script shebang line (`#!/bin/bash -e`)
- Call the script direct from bash using `./deploy.sh` and not run the script through `sh`.

Bear in mind that if `deploy.sh` **does** fail then the `cd ..` will **not** run (`&&` means run the next command if the preceding one succeeded), which would mean you were in the wrong directory to run the `deploy_service.sh`.  You would be better with `cd MAIN; sh deploy.sh; cd ..`, but I suggest replacing your call to `deploy.sh` with simpler alternative:

```
script:
  - sh authenticate.sh $DEPLOY_KEY
  - (cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh) 
  - sh deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING
  - sh deauthenticate.sh
```

This is not wildly different, but will result in the `cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh` to be run in a sub-process (that's what the brackets do), which means that the current directory of the overall script is not affected.  Think of it like "spawn a sub-process, and in the sub-process change directory and run that script", and when the sub-process finishes you end up where you started.

As other users have commented, you're actually running your scripts in sh, not bash, so all round this might be better:

```
script:
  - ./authenticate.sh $DEPLOY_KEY
  - (cd MAIN && ./deploy.sh) 
  - ./deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING
  - ./deauthenticate.sh
```

Comment: `deploy.sh` is returning a non-zero exit code (I use `set -e` in the script and I've checked the `$?` variable multiple times). I'm aware of the `&&` caveat and why the next statement is failing, but this is besides the point. The point is that both of the lines (`cd MAIN && sh deploy.sh && cd ..` and `sh deploy_service.sh MATCHMAKING`) are returning non-zero exit codes, but the executor is only error'ing on the second statement failure.